# Parsing a Puppet Librarian file (Puppetfile)

Tags: ruby, json, puppet

Can someone point me in the right direction of parsing a Puppetfile that is used with puppet-librarian?

Here's an example file:

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"

mod "puppetlabs/razor"
mod "puppetlabs/ntp", "0.0.3"

mod "apt",
  :git => "git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt.git",
  :path => 'apt'

mod "stdlib",
  :git => "git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib.git"
```

I want to be able to read the file in ruby and put it into a JSON format. I can't seem to find how they parse it, or anything that resembles a familiar format.

Comment: As far I understand Librarian uses Bundler-like syntax (https://github.com/bundler/bundler) I think you can investigate Bundler's source code, find classes which reads & parses configuration files.